# How to query VMs in Azure powerstate using tags

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I have a script that deallocates all VMs in the subscription based on the tags assigned - off hours and start them back up the next day using Jenkins. I want to be able to query these VMs based on the state (Running/Stopped(deallocated) and output it to a file.

Startup command - `az vm start --ids $(az resource list --tag Restart=${TAG_RESTART} --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].id" -o table)`

Query command -
`az resource list --tag Restart=yes --query "[].{Name:name,Group:resourceGroup,Location:location}" -o table`

This command returns output (Name, RG and location). I want it to also show the powerstate and possibly OS type once the restart script is complete. If it is also possible to export the output to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Tried this `az vm list --ids $(az resource list --tag Restart='yes' --query "[].{Name:name,Group:resourceGroup,Location:location,PowerState:powerState=='running'}" -o table)
`
Got this error
`az : ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: --ids Name           Group          Location 
-------------  -------------  ---------- hazrnv000er01  dvops-prod-rg  eastus
At line:1 char:1
+ az vm list --ids $(az resource list --tag Restart='yes' --query "[].{ ...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: az: erro...prod-rg  eastus:String) [], RemoteExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifie..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `az vm show -d --ids` to get powershell state.

Sorry, I don't have a Mac VM. On Linux VM, I use the following command to get it.

```
az vm show  -d --ids $(az resource list --tag Restart=shui --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].id"|jq -r ".[]") --query 'powerState'
```

On Mac, maybe you could use the following command.

```
az vm show -d --ids $(az resource list --tag Restart=${TAG_RESTART} --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].id" -o table) --query 'powerState'
```

You could get help by using `az vm show -h`

```
--show-details -d  : Show public ip address, FQDN, and power states. command will run slow.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful